# DefaultTableModel empty rows in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

```
public void show_teachers(){
    ArrayList<Teacher> list = TeacherList();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)TeacherTable.getModel();
    Object[] row = new Object[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
        row[0] = list.get(i).getID();
        row[1] = list.get(i).getFirst_Name();
        row[2] = list.get(i).getLast_Name();
        row[3] = list.get(i).getPhone();
        row[4] = list.get(i).getExperience();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

When I run the Jframe, the first 4 rows of the jTable (TeacherTable) is empty, all data are displayed below it thought, none are missing. How can I solve this?

**Edit**: Problem solved adding model.setRowCount(0) before the loop, but I'm having another issue that I forgot to mention, the Last_Name column is not showing any data/records.

Comment: Shouldn't `Object[] row = new Object[5];` be inside the loop?  You could also use `DefaultTableModel#setRowCount(0)` to clear all the previous rows

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used the setRowCount(0) worked like charm thanks! Just one more issue, it's not displaying any data in the Last_Name column (It was the same too before using the setRowCount(0)) I made sure the Last_Name is included in the constructors and the ArrayList Method.

Comment: @Dan, `not displaying any data in the Last_Name column` - then there is no data to display. You can easily verify this by just adding some debug code to display the value returned from the getLastName() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Teacher> list = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
    Teacher a = new Teacher("1", "Max", "Wonder", "012345", "not so good");
    Teacher b = new Teacher("2", "Brad", "Summer", "98765", "excellent");
    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    JTable table = new JTable();
    String headers[] = { "ID", "First_Name", "Last_Name", "Phone", "Experience" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0);
    table.setModel(model);

    for (Teacher teacher : list) {
        String id = teacher.getId();
        String first_Name = teacher.getFirst_Name();
        String last_Name = teacher.getLast_Name();
        String phone = teacher.getPhone();
        String experience = teacher.getExperience();

        Object[] data = { id, first_Name, last_Name, phone, experience };
        model.addRow(data);
    }

    System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 0));
    System.out.println(table.getValueAt(1, 1));
}

}
```

And Teacher class like:

```
public class Teacher {
    private String id, first_Name, last_Name, phone, experience;

    public Teacher(String id, String first_Name, String last_Name, String phone, String experience) {
        this.id = id;
        this.first_Name = first_Name;
        this.last_Name = last_Name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.experience = experience;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirst_Name() {
        return first_Name;
    }

    public String getLast_Name() {
        return last_Name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

}
```

Printline just for checking if table is not empty.

Output from example: 
1
Brad

Comment: Did this example help?